# Same dict variable value updated between tests in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have 2 tests that use the same dict for data. But when I update something in 1 test that will affect the second test. I want them to be independent.

data.py

```
a = {"data": {'data1': 'mydata',
              'data2': 'mydata2'
              }
     }
```

test_mytest.py

```
from data import a
import pytest

def test_1():
    test_data = a['data']
    test_data['data1'] = 'new data'


def test_2():
    test_data = a['data']
    assert test_data['data1'] == 'mydata'
```

When I run test_2 only it passes. But when I run both using pytest, test_2 is failing.
I want them to be passed when running together. Also, what can be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Either change the order of the tests, or `del a` after `test_1` and reimport it for `test_2`. But why are you changing the value of it in the first test, then asserting that the value is still the original in the second test?

Comment: I have a dict with sample data. I want to change the data between tests like name, and email. This code is just for a sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global mutable state is something best avoided in testing. There are no guarantees about the order in which your tests will be executed, and sharing state between tests can prevent speeding up the test suite by using a plugin like [pytest-xdist](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/) (which executes tests in parallel).

Instead, I would do it like this, giving each test a copy of the data by using a fixture

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def a():
    return {
        "data": {
            "data1": "mydata",
            "data2": "mydata2",
        }
    }

def test_1(a):
    test_data = a['data']
    test_data['data1'] = 'new data'

def test_2(a):
    test_data = a['data']
    assert test_data['data1'] == 'mydata'
```

If the data must be externally available:

```
# in conftest.py

import pytest
import copy

from data import a as a_source

@pytest.fixture
def a():
    return copy.deepcopy(a_source)
```

Note that if tests need to modify `data.a` itself, rather than *providing* a modified copy of `a` when calling a function for example, then you may prefer to simply patch the object in each test using pytest's `monkeypatch` fixture or using [`pytest-mock`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) plugin, e.g.:

```
def test_2(mocker):
    mocker.patch("data.a", {"k": "v"})
    ...
```

This kind of runtime patching only works if the contents of `data.a` are accessed *by the code under test* (i.e. not at import time). If it was already accessed before your test runs, then you're too late to patch.

Comment: Can I define this fixture in another file because I want to keep my data in another file instead of my test file?

Comment: I have a dict with sample data that needs to be changed in tests like name, and email. But when I change it in one it automatically reflects in another test when running all tests. What is the best way to store data currently I am using dicts in a python file because it can be directly used for APIs Payload.

Comment: Yes, I'll add an edit showing how to do that.